# MutliLine EditText Resize To Fit Content Within ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, layout, android-edittext

I have a multiLine EditText field that I'm defining within my layout for the row like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="320dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/lightblue" android:focusable="false">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp" android:layout_marginRight="14dp" android:focusable="false">
    <TextView android:textSize="12dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tvLabel"
        android:width="80dp" android:textColor="@color/lbl_color_alt"
        android:text="LABEL:" android:layout_marginRight="18dp"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/etValue"          
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvLabel" 
        android:singleLine="false" android:gravity="top|left"
        android:minLines="3"            
        android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:imeOptions="normal" android:textSize="12dp"             
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I can adjust the minLines attribute and the EditText will grow and shrink in size just fine.  However, I want the field to adjust it's size based on it's pre-populated content.  So that if the content contains 6 lines, it will adjust the height accordingly.  Is there something I need to do in the code to allow for this?  Ultimately, I want to handle readjusting the height in an onTextChanged listener as well (similar to iPhone).

Comment: So what is the question? EditText will adjust the height automatically according to content without any additional code. Also you have `getLineCount()` and `getLineHeight()` methods etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was programmatically hard setting the line height within the code with setLines() which was preventing the EditText from adjusting based on content.  I had done this MUCH earlier in the project and had forgotten all about it.